# how to make docker image of a backend which called python program from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, docker, containers

I have a javascript program which called a python program in every 2 minutes. I made an image of this backend file and pulled it in a container. After deploying the container shows spawn python ENOENT. the full error is as below:

```
Database up
running on 5000
events.js:353
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn python ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)

Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
```